# Trying to send the ltc coin uisng Bitgo js

Tags: node.js

I want to send the ltc using bitGo js api, but its not wokring there is issue of the amount.It works well for btc but not for ltc.I have tried to covert the amount into satoshi and litoshi but till it not working.Following is my code:

```
 const BitGoJS = require('../../src/index');
    const bitgo = new BitGoJS.BitGo({ env: 'test' });
    const Promise = require('bluebird');

    const coin = 'tltc';
    const basecoin = bitgo.coin(coin);
    // TODO: set your access token here
    const accessToken = null;
    const walletId = '5941ce2db42fcbc70717e5a898fd1595';
    // TODO: set your passphrase here
    const walletPassphrase = null;

    Promise.coroutine(function *() {
      bitgo.authenticateWithAccessToken({ accessToken: accessToken });

      const walletInstance = yield basecoin.wallets().get({ id: walletId });

      const newReceiveAddress1 = yield walletInstance.createAddress();
      const newReceiveAddress2 = yield walletInstance.createAddress();

      const transaction = yield walletInstance.sendMany({
        recipients: [
          {
            amount: '12341234', //not getting how to convert the  amount here
            address: newReceiveAddress1.address
          },
],
        walletPassphrase: walletPassphrase
      });
      const explanation = basecoin.explainTransaction({ txHex: transaction.tx });

      console.log('Wallet ID:', walletInstance.id());
      console.log('Current Receive Address:', walletInstance.receiveAddress());
      console.log('New Transaction:', JSON.stringify(transaction, null, 4));
      console.log('Transaction Explanation:', JSON.stringify(explanation, null, 4));
    })();
```

**Please suggest some solution how to resolve the amount issue while passing to the api for send method in bitGo js**

Comment: WHat is the issue? Amount issue means? Can you post error here?

Comment: if i tried to pass amount minimum than it gives error of dust value, else if the value is passed without the conversion than there is error of thershold